# Зачем нужен знак $ в названии файлов Java?

Tags: java, именование

разбирая чужой код иногда вижу файлы-классы в названии которых есть знак $, подскажите, для чего он нужен? Нигде не могу найти ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Оригинал ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14057101/5909792)

Символ `$` используется при генерации исходного кода или, редко, для доступа к уже существующим именам в устаревших системах.

Из [Java Language Specification on identifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.8):

> The $ character should be used only in mechanically generated source
> code or, rarely, to access pre-existing names on legacy systems.

---

[Пример использования в генерации кода](https://qr.ae/pGqifD):

Символ `$` используется как разделитель компилятора Java, чтобы указать, когда класс объявлен в другом классе. Для примера, класс `Foo` внутри `Bar` будет `Bar$Foo.class` когда скомпилируется, а анонимный класс внутри `Bar` будет `Bar$1.class`

[Пример использования в именах:](https://onlinegdb.com/UDnkmNuTS)

```
String c$sh = "cash";
System.out.println(c$sh);
```